# When i click phone button it goes to the app first page not the last one in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

There are multiple screens in my app but when I click the phone back button it goes to the first page not the last one in the stack. Will pop is not working

```
@overrideWidget build(BuildContext context) {   // double _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  appBar: AppBar(
    elevation: 0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    leading: IconButton(
      onPressed: (){
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios , color: Colors.black,),
    ),
    title: const Text('Now Playing',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),),
  ),
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
              color: Color.fromRGBO(10, 91, 144, 1),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  blurRadius: 1,
                  offset: Offset(0,2),
                  color: Colors.black12
                ),
              ]
            ),
```

Comment: how do you navigate, please share your code here.

Comment: The code you see this is the last page of my app but when i pressed phone back button it navigate to the first screen not the last one in a memory stack

Comment: can you include how you came on this page

Comment: Hey , The way you shared the code is so confusing ! Please share the First page and the second page,

Comment: I made some mistake and now it is solved thankyou guys for reply.

Answer (score -1):

please share how you are navigating to other screens, maybe you are using pushReplacement which will replace the current screen with new one

Comment: I am not using pushReplacement

Comment: The code is above you can see

Comment: I am using this   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:
                           (context)=>AudioScreen(
                             qari: widget.qari,
                             index: index+1,
                             list: surah,
                           )
                       ));

Comment: you should at least share all the your responsible codes for pushing the routes, as you say in last comment it seems you only have one interface, share all the necessary code in order I can help you